# How do I display better emoji in my apps?

Tags: unicode

I want to show emoji's clearly in my terminal app. If you print the snowman before it'll look awful

```
echo -e '\U2603'
```

output:

> ☃

However I found out there's something called "Variation Selectors". When you put a U+FE0F next to it, it looks significantly better

```
echo -e '\U2603\UFE0F'
```

> ☃️

(Alternatively `echo -e '\xe2\x98\x83\xEF\xB8\x8F'`)

Is there a way I can preview emoji's and compatible selectors? I have a few dozens I want to implement in my app and I'd like to choose the best looking one or the ones that flow together best

Comment: *"When you put a U+FE0F next to it, it looks significantly better."* - A minor FYI, but with certain software, these look identical (both images are "high quality", in case it matters). I had to switch browsers to see the difference in "low" and "high" quality versions.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Interesting. On my android phone both firefox and chrome show them as two separate image. Same as firefox on my desktop.  I don't have chrome/chromium installed tho